# With ltshipout, how to make some `picture` environment's content visible both if the pages are colored and only on the first page?

Tags: hooks, eso-pic, pagecolor

The following MCE shows that, if the pages are colored, a `picture` environment's content is:

- visible with `\AddToHook{shipout/background}` and `\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}` (but) on all pages,
- not visible with `\AddToHook{shipout/firstpage}`.

Is it possible to make some `picture` environment's content visible both if the pages are colored and only on the first page?

As shown, `eso-pic`'s `\AddToShipoutPictureBG*` is more or less able to do so (though the current page may not be the first one), but I'd like to not rely on it and emulate its behavior.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\Huge\bfseries\color{blue}#1}

\pagecolor{yellow}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(\textwidth,-.5\textheight){%
      \test{background}%
    }
  \end{picture}
}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(0,-.5\textheight){%
      \test{foreground}%
    }
  \end{picture}
}
\AddToHook{shipout/firstpage}{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(.5\textwidth,-.5\textheight){%
      \test{firstpage}%
    }
  \end{picture}
}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtTextCenter{%
    \test{eso-pic}
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Erh why the picture envs when `background` and `foreground` are already picture envs. Just use a `\put` right away.

Comment: What exactly is meant by `the pages are colored`?

Comment: @daleif Page are colored thanks to `xcolor`'s `\pagecolor`.

Comment: @daleif About `picture` envs with `background` and `foreground`, you're right, but it doesn't hurt :) BTW, `firstpage` also seems to not need any `picture` env.

Comment: Regarding the colored bg: here's the cool part of the new hooks, you can change the order, so you can set it up such that your addition to the bg is always applied after any colored bg. I think pagecolor also uses the hooks nowadays

Comment: @daleif Interesting: could you elaborate? About `pagecolor`, do you mean the package or the command provided by `xcolor`?

Comment: @daleif page color doesn't use the public hooks. We put it in an internal kernel hook to ensure that it is really behind everything.

Comment: Hook reordering is noted in the documentation. All I know is that switching to the hooks solved a long standing memoir bug regarding pagecolor and memoirs trimmarks, they often came in the wrong order. Now pagecolor is at the bottom. I don't remember if Ulrike fixed it.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer that was what I thought you did.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Does it mean page color is available without `xcolor`?

Comment: you need to load one color package.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I guess it is planned to add it to the `l3color` package.

Comment: yes, but not directly.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Hence an extra color package would be still necessary?

Comment: No long term it should work without it, but color and xcolor have a long history and many users and pagecolor is currently burried inside the color driver pdftex.def. Changing something here must be done with care.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shipout/firstpage` is the wrong hook. It is really at the very begin and as the documentation says

> It should only contain \special or similar commands needed to direct post processors handling the .dvi or .pdf output.

But you can use `\AddToHookNext` to get something only on the next page:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\Huge\bfseries\color{blue}#1}

\pagecolor{yellow}

\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{%
    \put(\textwidth,-.5\textheight){%
      \test{background}%
    }    
}
\AddToHookNext{shipout/foreground}{%
    \put(0,-.5\textheight){%
      \test{foreground}%
    }
}
\AddToHook{shipout/firstpage}{%
    \put(.5\textwidth,-.5\textheight){%
      \test{firstpage}%
    }  
}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG*{%
  \AtTextCenter{%
    \test{eso-pic}
  }%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Well... maybe my question was not clear enough: what I want in my MCE is the word "firstpage" to be visible on the first page (and only on the first page) even when the pages are colored.

Comment: Ah, OK, understood: what you suggest is to emulate `\AddToHook{shipout/firstpage}` with `\AddToHookNext{shipout/...}`. Nice! :)

Comment: shipout/firstpage is the wrong hook. It is really a the very begin and as the documentation says "It should only contain \special or similar commands needed to direct post processors handling the .dvi or .pdf output".